# How to test global.i18n.t

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

Google analytics has been added to the component in ReactJS and how to test since its giving undefined error while testing it.

```
render() {
return (
  <div className='form-wrapper'>
    <h2 className='register-form-title'>{global.i18n.t('great_offers.title')}</h2>
    <OTPForm
      otpChange={this._otpChange}
      errorMessage={this.state.error}
      handleSubmit={this._handleSubmit}
      valid={this.state.valid}
    />
  </div>
);
  }
```

In the above code while doing unit testing it says "can't read property t of undefined".So is there any way to initialize it to something in start.Moreover global.i18n.t isn't a valid variable name in JS ,so I can't initialize it also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Jest` provides a `global` object that can be used to set up global variables for unit tests.  Here is an example:

This component:

```
import * as React from 'react';

export default ()=> {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>{global.i18n.t('string_id')}</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

..can be tested like this:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';

import Component from './component';

// create global i18n object containing a spy as t()
global.i18n = {
  t: jest.fn((key) => 'global.18n.t() called with ' + key)
}

describe('Component', () => {

  it('should render and call global.i18n.t()', () => {
    expect(shallow(<Component />)).toMatchSnapshot();
    expect(global.i18n.t).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(global.i18n.t).toHaveBeenCalledWith('string_id');
  });

});
```

...producing this snapshot:

```
exports[`Component should render and call global.i18n.t() 1`] = `
<div>
  <h2>
    global.18n.t() called with string_id
  </h2>
</div>
`;
```

Note that the snapshot test is using [enzyme](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/) and [enzyme-to-json](https://github.com/adriantoine/enzyme-to-json#enzyme-to-json) which produce well formatted snapshots.